# Why is the entropy of deuterium greater than that of hydrogen gas

Tags: thermodynamics, hydrogen, entropy

Why is the entropy of deuterium more than that of hydrogen gas?

I thought about it but couldn't figure out a reason for why that would happen. Why would the number of neutrons in the nucleus affect the entropy of the gas?

Comment: I guess this has something to do with nuclear spin.

Comment: @ Ivan Neretin ;  yes nuclear spin seems to be is the cause, D has a spin of 1 whereas H has spin 1/2. In $\ce{H2}$ the ortho-para ratio is 3:1 but 2:1 in $\ce{D2}$  there is some detail here http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67316/why-do-spin-isomers-of-hydrogen-ortho-and-para-hydrogen-change-their-nuclear-s/67329#67329 which you will have to modify for deuterium.

Comment: also there is the fact that the rotational constant for deuterium is almost half that for hydrogen, $60.85 \pu{cm^{-1}}$, so many more rotational levels are occupied at a given temperature.

Answer (score 5):

The entropy can be split into three parts arising from translational, rotational and vibrational energies and using statistical mechanics each of there can be calculated from measure properties. The gases $\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{D2}$ differ in each of these three energies due to their differing mass and nuclear spin. The experimental values are hydrogen $130.7$ and deuterium $144.9 ~\pu{J mol^{-1}K^{-1}}$

The translational entropy is given by the Sakur-Tetrode equation, 
$$S_{trans} = R\left(\frac{5}{2}+\ln \left(\frac{V}{N} \right)+ \frac{3}{2}\ln\left( \frac{2\pi mkT}{h^2} \right )\right)$$
where *m* is the mass, *V* volume, *N* Avogadro’s number, *h* the Planck constant and *k* the Boltzmann constant. Assuming that the gases behave ideally the difference in entropy is small as it depends only on the mass difference all other terms being the same, so $S_{trans}$ is greater for $\ce{D2}$ than $\ce{H2}$ by $(3R/2)\ln(2) \approx 8.64~ \pu{ J mol^{-1}K^{-1}}$.

The vibrational entropy can be ignored at low temperature, for example at room temperature $kT \approx 210~ \pu{cm^{-1}}$ whereas the vibrational quantum are $4395$ and $3118~ \pu{cm^{-1}}$ for $\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{D2}$ respectively.

The contribution from the rotational motion depends both on the mass, as the moment of inertia determines the rotational constant, and on the nuclear spin which *via* the symmetry properties of Fermions and Bosons affects the weighting of the rotational energy levels.

To calculate the entropy the partition function $Z$ is required. Once this is obtained the entropy is calculated as
$$ S = k\ln(Z)+\frac{U}{T}$$
where the internal energy $U$ is 
$$U= kT^2\left ( \frac{\partial \ln(Z)}{\partial T} \right)_V$$

The partition function for odd mass number, assuming a rigid rotor model, is (see this answer for details [Why do spin isomers of hydrogen (ortho and para hydrogen) change their nuclear spin with temperature variance?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67316/why-do-spin-isomers-of-hydrogen-ortho-and-para-hydrogen-change-their-nuclear-s/67329#67329) )
$$Z_{odd}= \frac{g_n(g_n-1)}{2}\sum _{J=0,2,..} (2J+1)\exp(-B_eJ(J+1)/(k_BT)) +\\ \frac{g_n(g_n+1)}{2}\sum_{J=1,3,..} (2J+1)\exp(-B_eJ(J+1)/(k_BT)) $$

where $g_n = 2s_n+1$ where $s_n$ is the nuclear spin, $1/2$ for hydrogen and $1$ for deuterium. The rotational quantum numbers are *J* and $B_e$ the rotational constant assumed to be the same for all *J* but which differs between hydrogen ($60.85 \pu{cm^{-1}}$) and deuterium ($30.44 \pu{cm^{-1}}$) by a factor of two. (These rotational constants are not typical, values for most molecules which are heavier and have longer bonds are far smaller, for example, $\ce{F2}, B_e =1 \pu{cm^{-1}}$)

The partition function for even mass number
$$Z_{even}= \frac{g_n(g_n+1)}{2}\sum _{J=0,2,..} (2J+1)\exp(-B_eJ(J+1)/(k_BT)) +\\ \frac{g_n(g_n-1)}{2}\sum_{J=1,3,..} (2J+1)\exp(-B_eJ(J+1)/(k_BT)) $$
where the only difference is that due to the weighting (those terms in $g_n$ ) in from of the summations which run over even and odd values of *J*. Hydrogen has weightings $1$ and $3$, deuterium $6$  and $2$ respectively in the equations above.
Thus Z for hydrogen with $g_n=2$ is 
$$Z=1\cdot\Sigma (even~J) + 3\cdot\Sigma(odd~J)$$
and for deuterium, $g_n=3$
$$Z=6\cdot\Sigma (even~J) + 2\cdot\Sigma(odd~J)$$

At low temperatures the argument in the exponential is large meaning that the exponential is small. e.g. $exp(-large ~number) \rightarrow 0$  for all *J* terms except $J=0$ where the exponential is $1$. Thus in hydrogen the limiting partition function at low temperatures is $Z_{T\rightarrow 0}= 1 + 3(small~number) \approx 1$ and the limiting entropy is $S_{T\rightarrow 0 } R\ln(1) \rightarrow 0$; (and $U(0)=0$)

In deuterium the limit is $Z_{T\rightarrow 0 } = 6 + 2(small~ number) \rightarrow 6 $ and thus the limiting entropy is $S_{T\rightarrow 0 } R\ln(6) \rightarrow 14.9~ \pu{J mol^{-1}K^{-1}}$.
The change of rotational entropy with temperature is shown in the figure.

[image: entropy H2 D2]