# Which is more stable: Ortho or Para Hydrogen?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, hydrogen

It is known that Para-Hydrogen has opposite spin and Ortho-Hydrogen has same spin.
Therefore, the energy of Para-Hydrogen is lower than that of Ortho-Hydrogen.
Therefore, the stability order should be: **Para-Hydrogen > Ortho-Hydrogen.**

Is this true or is the stability order the opposite of what I predicted?. What is the reason for this stability order?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_isomers_of_hydrogen

Comment: It depends what you mean by 'stability' see also the answer here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67316/why-do-spin-isomers-of-hydrogen-ortho-and-para-hydrogen-change-their-nuclear-s

Answer (score 6):

At room temperature, about $75$% of $\ce{H2}$ is $\ce{o-H2}$ and $25$% is $\ce{p-H2}$. As the temperature drops, the relative amounts of $\ce{p-H2}$ increases. The two forms are in a temperature-dependent equilibrium $\ce{o-H2<=> p-H2}$, $\Delta H = \pu{-1.66 kJ/mol}$.

Ref. M. Eagleson, Concise Encyclopedia Chemistry, Walter de Gruyter Berlin, New York $1994$, 1202 p. ISBN 0-89925-4547-8.

Comment: This fails to answer OP's question: *why*?

Comment: So, which one is more stable?

Comment: Both are more stable. It is dependent on temperature and their ratio.